# Page Rank algorithm computing wrong page ranks

Tags: java, algorithm, pagerank

I am trying to implement a `page rank` algorithm.

I have total of 5 web pages (see image below). Following image represents a graph and shows which web page contains links to which page.

[image]

I have stored this linkage of web pages in a `HashMap` in such a way that each web page's unique link is stored as `key` and a `HashSet` containing all the links to the web pages that a given web page points to is stored as value of that key. (see image below)

[image]

Each web page is represented by its unique link. Above mentioned `HashMap` is represented in code as

```
HashMap<URI, HashSet<URI>> graph = new HashMap<>();
```

I have selected the `decay` value equal to `0.85` and `epsilon` equal to `0.00001`

**Problem**

After generating the above mentioned `Hashmap`, i am computing the `page rank` of each web page.

Final converged page ranks should be

[image]

but my actual page ranks are

```
Page A = 0.3170604814815385
Page B = 0.18719407056490575
Page C = 0.13199010955519944
Page D = 0.31131469834360015
Page E = 0.05244064005475638
```

Actual values for each page are OK as the difference between actual and expected value for each page is less than the selected `epsilon` value **except for the `Page D`**.

I have tried different inputs in to this `page rank` algorithm, no matter what i try, **i always have one or two web pages** for which **page rank values are not correct**. Algorithm is returning before all the pages have converged page ranks, i.e difference between old ranks and new ranks for each page less than `epsilon` value.

**Question**

What am i doing wrong? Why is my page rank algorithm returning page ranks before all of them have converged?

## Code

**Following function makes generates the `HashMap` shown in the images above.**

```
private static HashMap<URI, HashSet<URI>> makeGraph(HashSet<WebPage> webpages) {
        HashMap<URI, HashSet<URI>> webPagesGraph = new HashMap<>();
        HashSet<URI> singleWebPageLinks;

        HashSet<URI> availableWebPages = new HashSet<>();

        // add all the web pages available in data set in a collection
        for (WebPage doc : webpages) {
            availableWebPages.add(doc.getUri());
        }

        for (WebPage doc : webpages) {
            singleWebPageLinks = new HashSet<>();
            for (URI link : doc.getLinks()) {
                // if link is not pointing to the web page itself and is available in data set
                if (!link.equals(doc.getUri()) && availableWebPages.contains(link)) {
                    singleWebPageLinks.add(link);
                }
            }

            webPagesGraph.put(doc.getUri(), singleWebPageLinks);
        }

        return webPagesGraph;
}
```

**Following function computes Page Ranks**

```
private static HashMap<URI, Double> makePageRanks(HashMap<URI, HashSet<URI>> graph,
                                                   double decay,
                                                   int limit,
                                                   double epsilon) {

        // Step 1: The initialize step should go here
        HashMap<URI, Double> oldPageRanks = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<URI, Double> newPageRanks = new HashMap<>();

        double singleWebPageNewRank;
        int numLinkedPagesBySinglePage;
        double singleWebPageOldRank;
        boolean haveConverged = true;
        double rank;

        // provide ranks to each web page
        // initially the rank given to each page is 1/(total no. of web pages).
        // also give new page rank to each page equal to zero
        for (URI key : graph.keySet()) {
            oldPageRanks.put(key, (double) 1 / graph.size());
            newPageRanks.put(key, 0.0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            // Step 2: The update step should go here

            for (URI uri : graph.keySet()) {

                singleWebPageOldRank = oldPageRanks.get(uri);

                numLinkedPagesBySinglePage = graph.get(uri).size();

                // if any web page doesn't have any outgoing links to any other
                // web page, increase the new page rank for every web page
                if (numLinkedPagesBySinglePage == 0) {
                    for (URI u : newPageRanks.keySet()) {
                        singleWebPageNewRank = decay * (singleWebPageOldRank / graph.size());
                        saveNewRank(newPageRanks, u, singleWebPageNewRank);
                    }
                } // increase the new page rank of every web page that is pointed to
                // by current web page
                else {
                    for (URI linkedWebPageURI : graph.get(uri)) {
                        singleWebPageNewRank = decay * (singleWebPageOldRank / numLinkedPagesBySinglePage);
                        saveNewRank(newPageRanks, linkedWebPageURI, singleWebPageNewRank);
                    }
                }
            }

            // account for random user/surfer by adding (1 - decay) / (total no. of web pages)
            // to each web page's new rank
            for (URI uri : newPageRanks.keySet()) {
                rank = newPageRanks.get(uri);
                rank = rank + ((1 - decay) / graph.size());
                newPageRanks.put(uri, rank);

                // check for convergence
                // check if difference b/w old rand and new rank for each web page
                // is less than epsilon or not
                // if difference between old and new ranks is greater than or
                // equal to epsilon even for one web page, ranks haven't converged
                if (oldPageRanks.get(uri) - newPageRanks.get(uri) >= epsilon) {
                    haveConverged = false;
                }
            }

            if (haveConverged) {
                return oldPageRanks;
            } else {
                haveConverged = true;
                overWriteOldRanksWithNewRanks(oldPageRanks, newPageRanks);
            }
        }

        return oldPageRanks;
    }
```

Following two functions are utility functions that are called from within `makePageRanks` function

```
// save the new page rank for a given web page by adding the passed new page rank to
// its previously saved page rank and then saving the new rank
private static void saveNewRank(HashMap<URI, Double> newPageRanks, URI pageURI, double pageNewRank) {
      pageNewRank += newPageRanks.get(pageURI);
      newPageRanks.put(pageURI, pageNewRank);
}

// overwrite old page ranks for next iteration
private static void overWriteOldRanksWithNewRanks(HashMap<URI, Double> oldRanks, HashMap<URI, Double> newRanks) {
    for (URI key : newRanks.keySet()) {
        oldRanks.put(key, newRanks.get(key));
        // make new rank for each web page equal to zero before next iteration
        newRanks.put(key, 0.0);
    }
}
```

**Following is the simple WebPage class**

```
public class WebPage {

    private ArrayList<String> words;
    private URI uri;
    private ArrayList<URI> links;

    WebPage(URI uri, ArrayList<String> words, ArrayList<URI> links) {
        this.words = words;
        this.uri = uri;
        this.links = links;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    public URI getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public ArrayList<URI> getLinks() {
        return links;
    } 
}
```

**finally the `main` method for anyone wanting to see what input i am giving to page rank algorithm**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<URI> pageALinks = new ArrayList<>();
        pageALinks.add(createURI("www.b.com"));
        pageALinks.add(createURI("www.d.com"));
        URI pageAURI = createURI("www.a.com");
        WebPage pageA = new WebPage(pageAURI, new ArrayList<>(), pageALinks);


        ArrayList<URI> pageBLinks = new ArrayList<>();
        pageBLinks.add(createURI("www.c.com"));
        pageBLinks.add(createURI("www.d.com"));
        URI pageBURI = createURI("www.b.com");
        WebPage pageB = new WebPage(pageBURI, new ArrayList<>(), pageBLinks);


        ArrayList<URI> pageCLinks = new ArrayList<>();
        URI pageCURI = createURI("www.c.com");
        WebPage pageC = new WebPage(pageCURI, new ArrayList<>(), pageCLinks);


        ArrayList<URI> pageDLinks = new ArrayList<>();
        pageDLinks.add(createURI("www.a.com"));
        URI pageDURI = createURI("www.d.com");
        WebPage pageD = new WebPage(pageDURI, new ArrayList<>(), pageDLinks);


        ArrayList<URI> pageELinks = new ArrayList<>();
        pageELinks.add(createURI("www.d.com"));
        URI pageEURI = createURI("www.e.com");
        WebPage pageE = new WebPage(pageEURI, new ArrayList<>(), pageELinks);


        HashSet<WebPage> pages = new HashSet<>();
        pages.add(pageA);
        pages.add(pageB);
        pages.add(pageC);
        pages.add(pageD);
        pages.add(pageE);


        HashMap<URI, HashSet<URI>> graph = makeGraph(pages);
        HashMap<URI, Double> map = makePageRanks(graph, 0.85, 100, 0.00001); 
}
```

Comment: In the example you present, the computed rank for page D is strictly between 0.31131 and 0.31132.  The expected rank is 0.31132.  How, then, is the difference between actual and expected not less than your selected epsilon of 0.00001?  The difference appears to be only about half of your epsilon.  Overall, all of the computed ranks seem to be within epsilon of the expectations you give.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: In the example, the difference between expected and computed is *not* equal to epsilon.  You get a difference of epsilon if you first round the expected value to five fractional digits, but so what?  You need to cut your epsilon in half if you want it to be the rounded results that are within 0.00001 units of the expectation.  And, of course, you then need more precise expected values, too.

Comment: Your posted code does not run; the given web sites are not found.  We cannot reproduce your error to validate a solution.

Comment: As John Bollinger has already pointed out, you *are* within epsilon of your expected value, so the problem you describe is not exhibited by your example.  I caught the critical phrase in your comment: you're failing unit tests.  I don't see the output or tracing from that failure.

Comment: @Prune _Your posted code does not run_ i have posted my entire code except the `createURI` method which simply receives a `String` as an argument and returns the new instance of `URI` class

Comment: @Prune _I don't see the output or tracing from that failure_ that's because my actual code is part of a larger project and has other dependencies which makes it impossible to post here and the unit tests are part of that project. Code i have posted is the code that is responsible for computing page ranks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**:
You're testing for the wrong value.  You have to reduce your code's `epsilon` value to make the page rank get within 0.00001 of the desired value.  Two successive guesses within 0.00001 do not imply that result.

In addition to the problems I've noted in comments, I believe I see your problem.  It's a conceptual problem in convergence.  It appears that the requirement of the unit test is to converge to within `epsilon` of a predetermined value.  You have not written an algorithm for that.  Your test

```
if (oldPageRanks.get(uri) - newPageRanks.get(uri) >= epsilon)
```

Checks whether two successive approximations are within that value.  This does *not* guarantee that the new page rank is within `epsilon` of the ultimate value.  The calculus / topological definition of "close" neighborhood reads something like the following, for a guess `x` and a reference (correct) point `z`.

```
abs(x - z) < delta  ==>  abs(f(x) - f(z)) < epsilon
```

You may have confused `delta` and `epsilon`.

If the gradient of your approximation function is outside the range [-1, +1], then you will likely trip over this mistake.  You need to find the `delta` value for which this holds, and then use *that* quantity in place of your current `epsilon`.  This is a simple change in the `epsilon` value that you feed to your function.

Comment: _It's a conceptual problem in convergence_ i guess that is correct. Problem has been solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that [Wikipedia's description of PageRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) gives a very different convergence criterion than the OP's code uses.  It, too, has a numeric convergence threshold, but rather than comparing *individual* deltas to that threshold, it compares the length of *the whole delta vector* to the threshold.

Comment: I know.  However, the difference is clear enough from OP's context, and I went with that.